# Regex in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How would I go about transfering this regular expression:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

to oracle regular expression? 
from viewing https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540
I have made the following changes but with no success:

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+)*@
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$

CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Email VARCHAR2(500) CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(Email, '^[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$'))
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good use of a check constraint. There could be a legit email that doesn't match that regex.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2430400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're regex is pretty complicated and I don't know whether it would work in Oracle or not. I do know that Oracle won't recognize the non-capturing groups (starting with `?:`) as non-capturing. At the very least you'll have to specify the case-insensitive match parameter for `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Email, '^[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$', 'i') -- <-- Note 'i' at end!
```

What I would do is use a simpler regex, something like this:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

and rather than use a check constraint, add a column to the table to indicate that the address is a valid address (at least as far as regex is concerned) - then use a trigger to update that column based on the value in the email column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER email_valid
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF email ON user_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF REGEXP_LIKE(new.email, '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$', 'i') THEN
    new.valid_email := 'Y';
  ELSE
    new.valid_email := 'N';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

That way, you can allow email addresses that maybe don't match the regex and try to validate them individually. There are bound to be valid email addresses that don't match.

**UPDATE** The following regex will work (it is your regex but with the non-capturing groups turned into capturing groups:

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

You could use this with `REGEXP_LIKE()` as follows:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Email, '^[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''\*\+/=\?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$', 'i')
```